# Bash won’t recognize existence of closing single quote in systemd unit file

Tags: bash, systemd, archlinux

I have the following systemd unit file set to automatically update all Arch Linux and AUR packages at the same time (using the `yay` AUR helper, of course) while also attempting to temporarily add (and then delete after it’s done, for obvious reasons) a sudoers.d entry to briefly give nobody sudo access to pacman in order to get AUR packages updated:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automatic Update
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
SyslogIdentifier=autoupdate
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo \'nobody ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pacman\' > /etc/sudoers.d/autoupdate'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c \”XDG_CACHE_HOME=/var/tmp PWD=/var/tmp sudo -E -u nobody yay -Syuq --noconfirm --devel --timeupdate\”
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/rm -f /etc/sudoers.d/autoupdate
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that bash fails to acknowledge the existence of the closing single quote on the ExecStartPre line:

```
nobody: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `’`
nobody: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

This is of course despite the fact that manually typing `sudo bash -c ‘echo nobody ALL\=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pacman > /etc/sudoers.d/autoupdate’` into my shell succeeds without incident.

What could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: `’` is not `'`. And it's `"`, not `”`. And it's not `\'`, just `'`

Comment: Typed this up on my phone which unlike the computer itself has a tendency to auto-change straight quotes to slanted ones, so my point still stands. As for the escaped `'` it becomes automatically expanded to `'` by systemd before it’s passed to bash. If it was just `'` then systemd would filter it out and not let bash see it — would instead just be `bash -c` without the quotes and therefore without any ability to tell when the command ends or begins.

Comment: No, just `'`. I will find you an example, if you want. Look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/shadow.service` on your system. And don't `\\=` just `=` (and i should be I believe `ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:` or `ALL=(ALL)` I do not know if empty `ALL=` is valid, but my sudoers is bad). And consider using a separate builder account, not nobody - nobody should be nobody, he shouldn't be able to modify your system.

Comment: `shadow.service` doesn’t have any nested quotes being echoed to a file. In order for an existing service file to be analogous to what I’m trying to accomplish it would have to have an escaped string-within-a-string. And your “nobody should be nobody” argument is exactly why I delete the file afterwards; according to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Makepkg#Usage) use of nobody is recommended when building packages.

Comment: I do not understand. The service file you presented also does not have any "nested quotes".

Comment: `"nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pacman"` is a string within a string. Or at least supposed to be.

Comment: `nobody is recommended when building packages` Yes, when __building__ packages. Not for installation. Nobody is exactly recommend __because__ he can't do anything, like installing packages on your system. Once you give him permissions, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: Again, that’s exactly why my unit file was configured to delete the sudoers entry in the `ExecStartPost=` command. Which, as it turns out, needed to be changed to `ExecStopPost=` in order for this to work properly, as the answer to my own question points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the overcomplication of the issue was rooted in the use of `ExecStartPost=` instead of `ExecStopPost=`. Once I changed the former to the latter, the original version of the unit file from long before this was posted (which was far simpler) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

regardless of why you want to use sudo even though you are root..
and without thinking about your code..
Use a script instead

```
 ExecStartPre=/path/to/your/script prestart
 ExecStart=/path/to/your/script start
 ExecStartPost=/path/to/your/script poststart
```

your script

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
        prestart)  echo "nobody ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pacman" > /etc/sudoers.d/autoupdate;;
        start)     XDG_CACHE_HOME=/var/tmp
                   PWD=/var/tmp
                   sudo -E -u nobody yay -Syuq --noconfirm --devel --timeupdate;;
        poststart) rm -f /etc/sudoers.d/autoupdate;;
esac
```

Comment: [This is why](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Makepkg#Usage) — the AUR helper in question builds AND installs, doesn’t just install, and you *cannot* be root if you want to run `makepkg` on all those AUR packages to keep them just as up-to-date as the system itself. Of course it goes without saying that deleting nobody’s `sudoers.d` entry is exactly what my original version does, and, again, per answer to my own question, I did manage to solve my own problem anyway. Thanks though.